# making a basic three.js webgl example work in sails.js

Tags: javascript, linker, three.js, sails.js

I am trying to add the basic webgl particle example from three.js to the sails.js framework activityOverlord example in the default welcome screen.
So I first copy/paste in the linker/js folder the three javascript libraries I need, and I add them in the grunt file:

```
<script src="/linker/js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/stats.min.js"></script>
```

Then, I add the three.js code example to an .ejs file (here the /static/index.ejs file) the code does not work, while if I add the javascript code in the layout.ejs file before  then it displays the webgl thing beautifully...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%- title %></title>

<!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


<!--  
    Stylesheets and Preprocessors
    ==============================

    You can always bring in CSS files manually with `link` tags, or asynchronously
    on the client using a solution like AMD (RequireJS).  Or, if you like, you can
    take advantage of Sails' boilerplate asset management.

    By default, tylesheets from your `assets/linker/styles` folder are included
    here automatically.  Both CSS (.css) and LESS (.less) are supported.
    In production, your styles will be minified and concatenated into a single file.

    To customize any part of the built-in behavior, just edit your Gruntfile.
    For example, here are a few things you could do:

        + Change the order of your CSS files
        + Import stylesheets from other directories
        + Use a different or additional preprocessor, like SASS, SCSS or Stylus
-->

<!--STYLES-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/linker/styles/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/linker/styles/custom.css">
<!--STYLES END-->

<!--Added this so the client has access to the csrf tag and it's grabbed first service side on every page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.overlord = { csrf: "<%= _csrf %>" };
</script>

<!-- The sound file tht will play on activity events -->
<audio id="chatAudio">
<source src="/sounds/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="/sounds/notify.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="/sounds/notify.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> activityOverlord</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <% if (session.authenticated) { %>
          <li class="active"><a href="/user/show/<%= session.User.id %>"><%= session.User.name %> </a> </li>
        <% } %>
        <% if (session.authenticated && session.User.admin) { %>
        <li><a href="/user">User Administration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder2</a></li>
        <% } %>
      </ul>
      <div class="navbar-right">
        <% if (session.authenticated) { %>
          <a class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right" href="/session/destroy">sign-out</a>
        <% } %>
      </div>
      <% if (!session.authenticated) { %>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/session/create">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
      </form>
      <% } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%- body %>

<!-- <div class="container">
  <hr>
  <footer class="footer pull-right">
    <div>
      <a href="http://sailsjs.com/">sails.js</a> 
      <div>tutorial by irl nathan, with a bunch of help from cody, gabe, heather, mike, scott and zoli</div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>-->

<!--
    Client-side Templates
    ========================

        HTML templates are important prerequisites of modern, rich client applications.
    To work their magic, frameworks like Backbone, Angular, Ember, and Knockout require
    that you load these templates client-side.

    By default, your Gruntfile is configured to automatically load and precompile
    client-side JST templates in your `assets/linker/templates` folder, then
    include them here automatically.

    To customize this behavior to fit your needs, just edit your Gruntfile.
    For example, here are a few things you could do:

        + Import templates from other directories
        + Use a different template engine (handlebars, jade, dust, etc.)
        + Internationalize your templates using a server-side stringfile
          before they're served.
-->

<!--TEMPLATES-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jst.js"></script>
<!--TEMPLATES END-->


<!--

  Client-side Javascript
  ========================

  You can always bring in JS files manually with `script` tags, or asynchronously
  on the client using a solution like AMD (RequireJS).  Or, if you like, you can 
  take advantage of Sails' boilerplate asset management.

  By default, filesin your `assets/linker/js` folder are included here
  automatically.  Both JavaScript (.js) and CoffeeScript (.coffee) are supported.
  In production, your scripts will be minified and concatenated into a single file.

  To customize any part of the built-in behavior, just edit your Gruntfile.
  For example, here are a few things you could do:

      + Change the order of your scripts
      + Import scripts from other directories
      + Use a different preprocessor, like TypeScript

-->

<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script src="/linker/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/customValidate.js"></script>
<script src="/linker/js/underscore.js"></script>
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
<div id="container"></div>
    <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> webgl - buffergeometry - lines</div>



    <script>

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mesh;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            //

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 27, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 4000 );
            camera.position.z = 2750;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();


            var segments = 10000;

            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: true });

            geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new Float32Array( segments * 3 ), 3 );
            geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new Float32Array( segments * 3 ), 3 );

            var positions = geometry.getAttribute( 'position' ).array;
            var colors = geometry.getAttribute( 'color' ).array;

            var r = 800;

            for ( var i = 0; i < segments; i ++ ) {

                var x = Math.random() * r - r / 2;
                var y = Math.random() * r - r / 2;
                var z = Math.random() * r - r / 2;

                // positions

                positions[ i * 3 ] = x;
                positions[ i * 3 + 1 ] = y;
                positions[ i * 3 + 2 ] = z;

                // colors

                colors[ i * 3 ] = ( x / r ) + 0.5;
                colors[ i * 3 + 1 ] = ( y / r ) + 0.5;
                colors[ i * 3 + 2 ] = ( z / r ) + 0.5;

            }

            geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

            mesh = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            renderer.gammaInput = true;
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            //

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '350px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();
            stats.update();

        }

        function render() {

            var time = Date.now() * 0.001;

            mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.25;
            mesh.rotation.y = time * 0.5;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong to inject the three.js javascript code inside the ejs view files so that I could have different three.js programs starting in different views

Comment: Just found the solution to add webgl programs from three.js inside the ejs views in sails... :) simple really. The javascript code of three.js can bee added in the container of one of the views as long as the  <%- body %> in layout.ejs is placed below the <script src="/linker/js/three.min.js"></script> libraries... the result looks positively beautiful :) see: https://plus.google.com/111811850549054618411/posts/bMuE6VXpnUt

Comment: @Medhi.Khoury, you can post the above as an answer and accept it yourself if you think it will be helpful for others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution to add webgl programs from three.js inside the ejs views in sails... :) simple really. The javascript code of three.js can bee added in the container of one of the views as long as the <%- body %> in layout.ejs is placed below the  libraries... the result looks positively beautiful :) see image at : plus.google.com/111811850549054618411/posts/bMuE6VXpnUt